# What is Ionic X?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I go through the Ionic Website, I can't figure out what  **X**  means? They just mentioned "**Low code your developers will love**".

https://ionicframework.com/x

Is **X** denotes anyone from the following languages(Angular, React, Vue, Javascript) or different?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I contacted Ionic Support regarding their current offering of Ionic Studio and whether it was still available. In case you would not know what Ionic Studio is: it is their IDE for developing Ionic-based applications.

In a nutshell:  **Ionic X is the next phase of Ionic Studio**.

See the below extract of the response I got from Ionic Support:

"... *We believe there is a lot of value in low code solutions and we believe Ionic can build the first developer-friendly low code platform that will be based on open standards and modern technology!*

*We’ve discovered through working on the first version of Ionic Studio that what matters to our user base is building apps from start to finish. Our customers want to be able to accomplish the 90% with low code and have the ability to pass their app along to their skilled developers to refine the last 10%.*

*In order to achieve this vision and bring you a complete solution, ready to help you rapidly bring apps to market, we’ve decided to branch this project into the second phase of Ionic Studio, currently envisioned as Ionic X.*  ..."

Hope this answers your question!